# What's purpose of __linecapp in getline, when it'll auto resize?

Tags: c, getline, stdio

It's all about second parameter of getline in stdio.h,

I'll name it 'n' or '__linecapp' below.

According to the [document](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html):

> If the
> buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it
> with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.

It'll automatically update line capacity, then why should we input __linecapp?

P.S Someone ask before, but discussion didn't explain when we need it, or how to make it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Heap allocation is a relatively expensive operation so you want to minimize those to be efficient.

`getline()` will only allocate a new buffer if requested (by setting `lineptr` and `n` to NULL).  Otherwise it will reuse the buffer that `lineptr` points to, and for that it needs to ensure the buffer is large enough.  If the size of the buffer is not known, then `realloc()` would have to be called on every invocation to ensure it's big enough.  `getline()` will also resize the buffer more than `1` byte at a time (to make it amortized linear time instead of n^2), for example, I read `3` bytes (size) but it allocated `120` bytes (capacity).

Comment: So is it like telling getline: "hey~ capacity start from this number, it may reduce price of allocating memory, but if line takes more space, just reallocate yourself. Me developer have tried my best!"